# How can I check a checkbox in Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium in Java to test the checking of a checkbox in a web application. Here's my code:

```
boolean isChecked = driver.findElement((By.xpath(xpath1))).isSelected();
```

But this code returns incorrect value. The checkbox in the HTML:

#### Active checkbox

```
<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"></span>
</div>
```

#### Inactive checkbox

```
<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank"></span>
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem in Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use isSelected(), because it is not a standard HTML input element.

My suggested solution is: you can take class attribute and check with active one:

```
if(driver.findElement((By.xpath(xpath1))).getAttribute('class') == 'ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active')
  return True
else
  return False
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is mainly because the checkbox that you have created is not a standard input checkbox element that HTML has, but a custom one. In order to check it, you can perform a click operation on it and see if it works.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.ui-chkbox-box)).click(); // Check the checkbox
```

In order to verify whether it's checked, you can verify the class of the element which adds `ui-state-active` to the div element when it's active.

Here's how -

```
try{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.ui-state-active')); // Find the element using the class name to see if it exists
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.println('Element is not checked');
}
```

Or get the class attribute of the element and then use it to see if it exists.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.ui-chkbox-box')).getAttribute('class');
```

Comment: On the page has more than 10 checkbox same attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it, but it is not a too pretty solution:

```
String a = driver.findElement((By.xpath(xpath1))).getAttribute("class");
System.out.print(a.contains("ui-state-active"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For more tricky situations:

Checkboxes have a pseudo CSS selector, "checked".

So you can add 'checked' to your CSS selector like this:

```
let check = !!driver.findElement({css:"div.ui-chkbox-box:checked"});
```